# string replace regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a url that looks like this

```
http://localhost:12472/auctions/auction-12/lots/sort/something/12
```

I want to replace this with the following url

```
http://localhost:12472/auctions/auction-12/lots/sort/somethingelse/12
```

where `somethingelse` is any injected string and `something` is any other string

How do I do this with Javascript string replace using Regex?

**Edit**

So, the rule is this

x/sort/y/z

I want to replace y with something else.

Comment: `'http://localhost:12472/auctions/auction-12/lots/sort/Relevance/12'.replace('/Relevance/', '/something/')`?

Comment: Why you're looking for regex. Simple `String#replace` can also work.

Comment: IS the URL an actual window URL or just a string?

Comment: Read [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Relevance can be something other than Relevance

Comment: @SachinKainth so, what tell you which part of the string you want to replace?

Comment: Is there a rule? 2nd from last segment? 5th segment? segment after `/sort/` ?

Comment: @SachinKainth Then how on earth are we supposed to write it? A variable string, could appear anywhere in another variable string.. and you want it replaced with a variable string. There must be some sort of rule for figuring out which part of the url needs replacing

Comment: jQuery has no string replacement or regexp functions. They're part of ordinary Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
newstr = str.replace(/\/sort\/[^\/]+\/([^\/])$/, '/sort/somethingElse/$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Find and Store value
var myURL = 'http://localhost:12472/auctions/auction-12/lots/sort/Relevance/12';
//Retrieve variable and replace regex match with new value (This can be another variable to)
myURL.replace(/Relevance/i, "Something");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mystr = 'http://localhost:12472/auctions/auction-12/lots/sort/something/12'
var newPart = 'somethingelse';
var newstr = mystr.replace(/([^\/]+\/sort\/)[^\/]+(\/[^\/]+)$/,'$1'+newPart+'$2')

console.log(newstr); //http://localhost:12472/auctions/auction-12/lots/sort/somethingelse/12
```

Regular expression visual & demo:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/APZZsRRah4VbD5N0)

Answer (score 0):

Something more abstract to capture the part of the path just before any path ending in digits:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:12472/auctions/auction-12/lots/sort/something/12';
url.replace(/[^\/]+(?=\/\d+$)/, 'somethingelse');
```